# Justification Of Equation Of Perpendicular Bisector

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem where I have to write the equation in point slope form for the perpendicular bisector of $A(7,9)$ and $B(-3,5)$. I came up with

$$ y= \frac{2}{5}x + \frac{31}{5}$$

First of all is this correct, and I second I'm supposed to write the justification of this, is the justification just the work I did to get the answer?

Comment: Slope should be -5/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of the line joining $A$ and $B$ has gradient $\frac {9-5}{7--3}=\frac 4 {10} = \frac 25$.

The perpendicular bisector is perpendicular to this , so has gradient $-\frac 52$

The perpendicular bisector must go through the midpoint $M(\frac{7+-3}2, \frac{9+5}2)$ which gives $M(2, 7)$